# In Tkinter's canvas is it possible to have mouse events ignore transparent parts of an image?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've got an image (drawn in Pillow) with a transparent background. I can add this onto a Tkinter canvas via create_image() and bind mouse events to it, e.g. button clicks.

However, Tkinter canvas triggers the mouse events for the entire image **including** the transparent background.

Is there any way in Tkinter to have mouse events ignore an image's transparent pixels?

Everything else works fine and as expected, however I've not been able to find any option or if it's even possible to have Tkinter ignore mouse events for transparency in images?

Thanks in advance to anyone who knows!

EDIT2: On request, more details. The situation is that I've got a map which serves as the background of the canvas object, on this map I draw routes, and I want those routes to react to mouse events such as clicks.

```
for route in travel_routes:

    route_map = route.draw_route_map(canvas_width, canvas_height)
    self.CanvasTravelMapRoutes.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(route_map))
    
    self.CanvasTravelMap.create_image(
        0, 0, image = self.CanvasTravelMapRoutes[-1], anchor = tk.NW, tag = (route.RouteID, 'travel_route') )

self.CanvasTravelMap.tag_bind('travel_route', "<Button-1>", self.travel_canvas_route_click)
```

In the route class, the draw_route_map method works as follows:

```
route_map = Image.new("RGBA", (canvas_width, canvas_height), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(route_map)

draw.line()
draw.ellipse()
etc. etc.
```

The result is a route_map image laid on top of the canvas, but which is mostly transparent except for the lines and circles drawn to mark the route's course across the map.

All elements of this code function as designed, except that the canvas mouse events also respond to the transparent parts of the route_map images. Obviously, this means any click anywhere on the canvas always selects whichever route_map is on top and not the specific line/mark being clicked on.

Comment: It's not 100% but I dont think this is possible. I don't know what you want to do but it seems a bit more complex than just some usual UI. Tkinter has very limited possibilities in this area. In my opinion you do not have correct library for your purposes.

Comment: @Maraz it is possible, is it simple? depends, but to say that `tkinter` has limited possibilities... I would say that you can create literally any GUI with it, maybe it doesn't have built-in methods for everything (no GUI library has those) but you can make use of the existing ones enough to make something work (the only issue is that `tkinter` is kinda slow so maybe you can't create some advanced video editor for high quality videos)

Comment: @Matiiss and Maraz: Hi thanks for the discussion! Just to be clear: I'm not trying to do anything more complicated than have buttons with somewhat more complex shapes. Drawing the 'button' image in Pillow with non-clickable areas as transparent background was the first and most straightforward implementation I could think of.

Comment: @nadafanboy can you show exactly how you get the image?

Comment: @Matiiss I've edited the post. I hope this helps clarify what I'm asking!

Comment: @nadafanboy I posted an answer if you want to check out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you wanted to have this kind of collision you could try this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests


url = 'http://media-s3-us-east-1.ceros.com/g3-communications/images/2019/01/15/05eea4b9b9ce010d2dd6b0c063d2f5ca/p1-blob.png?imageOpt=1&fit=bounds&width=893'
data = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
image = Image.open(data)


def on_opaque(event, offset, img):
    print('clicked on bounding box')
    x, y = event.x - offset[0], event.y - offset[1]
    if img.getpixel((x, y)) != 0:
        print('clicked on opaque pixel')


root = Tk()

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

canvas = Canvas(root, height=image.height, width=image.width, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

offset_x, offset_y = 0, 0
c_img = canvas.create_image(offset_x, offset_y, image=photo, anchor='nw')
canvas.tag_bind(c_img, '<Button-1>', lambda e: on_opaque(e, (offset_x, offset_y), image))

root.mainloop()
```

I use image from internet, you can use your own, it is just that you can test it immediately. Basically it binds the whole image to button click, but then in the callback it additionally checks if the click was in a position where there is not a transparent background, also be careful with fake transparent background, I then suggest that you set the background of canvas to black and see if the bg behind image is black too.

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton! I didn't do it exactly like you suggest, but you showed me how to make it work by way of getpixel. It's working properly now!

Comment: @nadafanboy I'm gonna guess that you used it to tell which route it was based on pixel value?

Comment: Yes, instead of a tag_bind I bound to the canvas itself, so on a click anywhere on the canvas it iterates through all drawn routes to check if any was clicked on. Using getpixel() to check for transparency (I found that transparent pixels don't return a 0 but a (0, 0, 0, 0) but obv same differences). Because my route images are the same size as the canvas, I don't need to account for offset. Haven't tried it yet but I'm assuming similar method will work with a motion bind for hovering over specific routes. Again thanks a ton, I would never have thought of doing it like this myself!